# TPanel color is black no matter what

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I just activated the themes in my Windows XP (usually I work using the classic Win9x look) and I have seen that two panels are pure black. Other panels are ok (color = clBtnFace).
What these 2 panels have in common is their parent. Both are placed directly on a TForm. If I move them to a different parent (another panel for example) the have the appropriate color.

Delphi 7, win xp pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another grandiose Delphi bug. I started do delete stuff from my project and recompile the project. After one hour I finally went to the main form. I deleted the XPManifest control and now, magically, the program works.

The new issue (XPMan) is discussed here: [TPanel color is black when I drop a XPManifest control on my form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233568/tpanel-color-is-black-when-i-drop-a-xpmanifest-control-on-my-form)

---

Edit:
Removing the XPMan is not enough. You will have to delete also the RES files. For large applications it may take a while to manually reconstruct that file. Maybe it works to big into that file and manually remove the resources added by XPMan.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the panels do not have `ParentColor=false` and `Color=clBlack` assigned to them, and that `ParentBackground=true` is assigned.

Comment: Actually, when working on themed systems, parentcolor gets reset on form creation. You have to put that property back in a FormCreate method to clean up the problem.