# TPanel color is black when I drop a XPManifest control on my form

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

This is a continuation of a previous post: [TPanel color is black no matter what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233262/tpanel-color-is-black-no-matter-what)

The problem is this: All TPanels that have a TForm as parent, turn black when I use a XPManifest. Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other solution for this than deleting the XPManifest.

Answer (score 5):

Change `Panel1.ParentBackground` to `true` then change it back to `false`.

Comment: I'm still doing some stuff in D7. I didn't expect this answer to work, but it did (after I'd tried many other things).